# Error when installing http-server: No matching version found for ecstatic@^3.0.0

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm new to front end development and now I have to maintain an AngularJS application. I'm trying to install `http-server` in order to test my app, but when I run the `npm install http-server -g` command, I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ecstatic@^3.0.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you ir one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'http-server'
npm ERR! notarget
```

I haven't found any solution. Have you guys seen this error before?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They've had a security issue with versions prior to 4 and have removed download links for them. You can find more details here: https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-ecstatic/issues/255 .

You'll either need a cached version from before or move to a newer version.

Answer (score 7):

They are working on a fix.
This is a fork on NPM:

```
npm i http-server-legacy
```

or

```
yarn install http-server-legacy
```

Source: https://github.com/indexzero/http-server/issues/521#issuecomment-488843797

Answer (score 3):

The maintainer has now patched the library, and the following versions should now be available:

> 2.2.2, 3.3.2, 4.1.2

[Reference](https://github.com/jfhbrook/node-ecstatic/issues/255)